# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: firebase global code

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reference

I keep getting the error: ReferenceError:

Can't find variable: `firebase global code@/script.js:10:26 at /script.js:10:26`

I initialized it properly and all but when I reference the variable it throws an error. My code looks right so far as per initializing the variable but here's my code(I have included both my html file and my javascript file).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <label>User ID:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="userId" /><br>

  <label>First Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="firstName" /><br>

  <label>Last Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" /><br>

  <label>Age:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="age" /><br>

  <button id="addBtn">ADD</button>
  <button id="updateBtn">UPDATE</button>
  <button id="readBtn">READ</button><br>
  <button id="removeBtn">REMOVE</button>


  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBRhn_MY7TNnTDPbf2WXU-5bio6zpd70UI",
    authDomain: "myawesomeproject-69436.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myawesomeproject-69436.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "myawesomeproject-69436",
    storageBucket: "myawesomeproject-69436.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "299772211749",
    appId: "1:299772211749:web:b503b7a4fb44a8676f05cc",
    measurementId: "G-6MH270KGNL"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
</html>
```

```
const database = firebase.firestore();
const usersCollection = database.collection('users');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const ID = usersCollection.doc();

  ID.set({
    first_name: firstName.value,
    last_name: lastName.value,
    age: age.value
  })

  .then(() => {console.log("data written");})
  
});
```

Comment: Which line of code are you referring to?  How does the second bit of code relate to the first?  Is there a script include missing?

Comment: The first is my html code and the second  is my javascript. The line the error refers to is "const database = firebase.firestore();"

Comment: So, how are they related?  How are you running that second code?  I don't see a script include for it.  I only see script includes for Firebase SDKs.

Comment: I added all my code to the question now so you can get a better idea of how it looks and runs, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script include for script.js must happen **after** the firebase SDK scripts, so they can use the global `firebase` variable.  So, just move it after:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script>
// code that includes firebase.initializeApp()
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```